# Google drive API data doesn't match data in UI

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I'm trying to connect to Google drive to download files to be consumed by a web application.
I'm using a `Service Accounts` key that I generated in Google Cloud console. 
When I list the files with the API I get only 1 folder, but when I look at the UI I see a few files and 1 folder (not the one that I see with the API).

This is a code I use, an indication on what I'm doing wrong?

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def init_connection():
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'credentials.json'

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)

    return credentials

def list_files():
    creds = init_connection()

    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = drive_service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute(
    print(results)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this answer?

### Issue and workaround:

From `When I list the files with the API I get only 1 folder, but when I look at the UI I see a few files and 1 folder (not the one that I see with the API).`, I thought that you might have compared the result value retrieved from the service account with the result value shown in your Google Drive. If it's so, the Drive of the service account is different from your Google Drive. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue.

In order to retrieve the files and folders in your Google Drive using the service account, how about the following workaround?

### Workaround :

In this workaround, at first, please share a sample folder in your Google Drive with the email of the service account. And, retrieve the file list using the following script.

#### Sample script:

```
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def init_connection():
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = 'credentials.json'

    credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE)
    # or, the following script.
    # SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
    # credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE, scopes=SCOPES)

    return credentials


def list_files():
    creds = init_connection()

    drive_service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)
    # Call the Drive v3 API
    folderId = '###'  # Please set the folder ID of the shared folder with the service account.
    results = drive_service.files().list(pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)", q="'" + folderId + "' in parents").execute()
    print(results)
```

### References:

- [Files: list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files)

Comment: Sharing the files with the service account email did the trick. Add scope didn't change anything

Comment: @shlomiLan Thank you for replying and testing both workarounds. From your replying, I removed the workaround 1 from my answer. Thank you, too.